# update calculated value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one with columns: title, vote which shows the vote for each title. Now I have a second table with the columns name and avg_vote. I want to update the value of tb2.avg_vote to the average of tb1.vote.

I tried the following which doesn't work:

```
update tb2, tb1
set tb2.avg_vote = avg(tb1.vote)
where tb2.name = 'user';
```

I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

It does work when you delete the avg() part, but then it doesn't give the average but just the first value.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
update tb2 set avg_vote = (select avg(vote) from tb1) where name = 'user';
```